# structure of the abelian semigroup defined on a metric space

Tags: abstract-algebra, topological-groups, semigroups

Let $u_1,u_2 \in \mathbb{R}$. Let us define the binary operation $*$ as

$$u_1*u_2=u_1+u_2-\ln\left[ \exp^{u_1}+\exp^{u_2} \right].$$ It can be checked that this operation is commutative and associative which makes it a semi-group.

How can I find its kernel, sub-semi-groups and other substructures ("minimal blocks")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $$ e^{a*b}=\frac{e^ae^b}{e^a+e^b}$$
we obtain  magma isomorphism $\langle\Bbb R,*\rangle\to \langle (0,\infty),\circ\rangle$, $x\mapsto e^x$, where $\circ$ is defined as
$$ a\circ b = \frac{ab}{a+b}.$$
We can take this further by noting that
$$ \frac1{a\circ b}=\frac1b+\frac1a.$$
Thus, we obtain an isomorphism of magmas $$\begin{align}\langle R,\circ\rangle&\to \langle (0,\infty),+\rangle\\x&\mapsto e^{-x}\end{align}$$
and thus can infer all we want to know about $\langle R,\circ\rangle$ from the better-known $\langle (0,\infty),+\rangle$. (In particular, we infer without direct computation that the magma $\langle R,\circ\rangle$ is in fact a abelian topological semigroup without a neutral element, with cancellation law, etc.

Comment: Ok, so I conclude that the structure of my semigroup coincides with the structure of the better-known $\langle (0,\infty),+\rangle$.  Where can I look it up?